# Retrieving locale information using a java program

Tags: java, internationalization, locale

Is it possible to store locale information in a spring bean and retrieve it in a java application?

Scenario...

I am passing the locale parameter along with the url as follows:

```
url?lang=fr
```

Spring context.xml  configuration looks like below:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
<property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"/>
<property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" /> 
<property name="cookieMaxAge" value="604800"/>
```

```
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
  <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Need to fetch locale data from the applicationcontext.xml in my java application.
Is there a way to store current locale to a bean in .xml file and retrieve it in java application.

I am not able to retrieve the changed locale into my java application. 
How can I get the locale information in my java application whenever it is changed?

Comment: Show us some code. Is it Spring WS or REST? It should be straightforward to add a new param for a request, but we need some details about what have you tried.

Comment: Hi Please find the application-context.xml file above

Comment: its for i18n implementation

Comment: There are tons of config issues that can go wrong, the easiest is to check a working example. Here's a [sample tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/26/internationalization-i18n-support-in-spring-3-example-tutorial/), you should check it.

Comment: The example that you gave is for i18n. I have understood that part and implemented it.But I don't have any clue as to how can the changed locale value be retrieved in a java class. I have tried                Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();                   in my application but it's giving null value.